# invertible matrices and factorising matrices confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say $A \neq I$ and $A^2=I$ my teacher told me that this equation can be factorised into $(A-I)(A+I)=0$ and I can conclude that $A=-I$ if $A-I$ is invertible but I do not really get the last part.. I understand that it can be factorised but what has it to do with $A-I$ being invertible and its kernel being trivial?

Comment: What about $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$? This matrix is both invertible and satisfies $A^2=I$.

Comment: @PeterForeman I meant to put $A-I$ being invertible sorry.

Comment: If $A-I$ is invertible then you can multiply by the inverse of $A-I$ on both sides to conclude $A+I=0$, hence $A=-I$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2=I$, then $(A-I)(A+I)=0$. So, if $A-I$ is invertible, then
$$
     0 = (A-I)^{-1}(A-I)(A+I) = A+I \implies A=-I.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments; if $A-I$ is invertible then there exists a matrix $B$ such that $B(A-I)=I$, so
$$A+I=I(A+I)=B(A-I)(A+I)=B\cdot0=0,$$
and hence $A=-I$.